# Is the "vanishing locus" of a section of a quasi-coherent sheaf closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

Suppose $A$ is a (possibly noetherian) ring and M a (possibly finitely generated) $A$-module. Consider for $m \in M$ the set
$$\{m = 0\} := \{\mathfrak p \subset A \text{ prime ideal} \,|\, m_{\mathfrak p} \in \mathfrak p M_{\mathfrak p} \} \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A).$$
Is $\{m = 0\}$ a closed subset of $\operatorname{Spec} A$? If so, does it have a "better" canonical subscheme structure than the reduced one?

I realized that I should at least suppose that $\operatorname{Ann}(m) = 0$, because for $\mathfrak p \notin V(\operatorname{Ann}(m))$, we have $m_{\mathfrak p} = 0$. So for example if $A = k[x,y]$, then
$$m = \overline y \in k[x,y] / (x)$$
vanishes exactly on $\mathbb A^2 \setminus \{x = 0, y \neq 0\}$.

Comment: This should be true at least for $M$ locally free, so maybe it’s true under your hypothesis

Comment: Typically, for finitely generated modules, giving an element in $M$ corresponds to a map $A\to M$ which induces a map $M^*\to A$, by taking duals. The image is an ideal giving the correct closed subset under mild hypothesis.